# jquery uitabs off by -1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I dynamically add and remove tabs. I now try to go to a specific tab by index as follows:

```
var elem = ('[role="tabpanel"][symbol="'+symbol+'"][exchange="'+exchange+'"]');
var index = $(elem).index();
$("#tabs").tabs({active: index});
```

The relevant html code is:

```
<div id="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" tabcounter="2" symbol="MSFT" exchange="NASDAQ"></div>
<div id="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" tabcounter="3" symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="tabs-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" tabcounter="4" symbol="YHOO" exchange="NASDAQ" style="display: block;"></div>
```

In order for it to work I need to do:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({active: index-1});
```

I'm not sure why the "-1" is required.

I'm not sure why or what I'm messing here...

Answer (score 0):

The indexing of most things in computer science starts at 0, not 1. The jQuery Tabs widget follows this convention.

Comment: That should be fine no? Since var index = $(elem).index() shouldn't it automatically give me the correct value for the index (regardless of where the count started)??